# Difference between installing maven and the maven eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

So I d/led and installed maven from here:
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

But the tutorial I'm following only installs a plugin for eclipse from the eclipse marketplace.

This is a really noob question, but what's the difference between the two?

Comment: One's for Eclipse. One's for the command line.

Comment: This question is so basic and the answer is so obvious now. Do you think I should delete the question? Or maybe it can come in handy for someone else?